# WinSCP recursively find all files with certain extension and upload it to FTP server

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp, winscp

I need to recursively find `*.log` files at `C:\` and send them to my server using WinSCP. I've experimented with `put` but it can only send files from a given directory. After that I've tried using cmd's `dir` to get the list of required files and then send them using WinSCP, but I can't both open connection AND send files: `cmd` prompt changes to `winscp>` after I open connection from `cmd`.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`-filemask` switch in `put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#filemask) to upload only files [matching a mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask):

```
put -filemask=*.log C:\ /remote/path/
```

---

If you want to avoid "uploading" folders that contain no `*.log` files:

```
put -filemask=*.log -rawtransfersettings ExcludeEmptyDirectories=1 C:\ /remote/path/
```